# How to restrict the allowable permission-set for the OAuth 'scope' parameter (restricting scope)

Tags: oauth, scope, facebook-apps, facebook-oauth, facebook-login

I want to use Facebook as an authentication source for my application (a website) users. I do not want my application to have anything but basic and email permissions. Thus, my application must not be able to publish to a user's wall for example. In other words, I want to restrict the allowable set of values for the scope parameter and I want this restriction to occur on the application's configuration pages (on the Facebook site itself).

Normally this would be easy, just specify 'email' for the scope parameter of the OAuth URL/call.

However in this case there is another factor and this is: a hacker may gain access to the app and change the OAuth call to specify more permissions. Then an unsuspecting user will typically (or at least possibly) grant those permissions and the hacker will be able to grab the OAuth token and perform actions on behalf of that user.

I'm not interested in discussing the whys of this issue, just in finding of there is a way to specify that my application can only use a specific set of values for the scope parameter. Ideally this specification of the scope restriction be done in the application configuration page on Facebook itself.

However, I am interested in alternate solutions that involve using SAML, OpenID or some other authentication only mechanism (even if I cannot get the users email address). I'm not interested in using RPX.

Please note: this is a complex question not a simple one. I have searched far and wide for an answer and have just found what amounts to the opposite of this question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's not possible to restrict the scope at application configuration level.

I'd say the tidiest workaround would be to query the permissions of a user on signup, check that they match the allowed permissions, and subscribe to the (permissions realtime updates)[http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/]. Your app will be notified of any changes in permissions granted to users.

This should allow you to block any server side API calls through application logic, or (ban)[https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/#banned] a user which escalates permissions.

Comment: Interesting idea. Looking at the realtime doc, it looks like it sends requests for changes but not the very first time a user authorizes the application.

Comment: You can check that first time using /me/permissions. So, confirm they're correct, and the realtime will ensure they *stay* correct.